# react jsx expression with style

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<Link style={!id && {'cursor':'normal'}}>link</Link>
```

Anything wrong with my above jsx expression? trying to add a style if id is not defined.

Answer (score 4):

Use ternary operator.

```
<Link style={!id ? { cursor:'normal' } : null}>link</Link>
```

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, [the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#style) doesn't discuss this.

But empirically, no, you can't do it like that because when there is an `id`, you'll end up with `style={false}`, which React doesn't like (it complains that *"The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string."* even though `false` isn't a string).

Empirically, using either `null` or `undefined` works, which means either the conditional operator:

```
style={id ? null : {cursor: "normal"})
```

Example:

```js
const Foo = props => <div style={props.id ? null : {color: "green"}}>Testing</div>;

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Foo id="a" />
    <Foo />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
```

...or adding `||`, which is fairly ugly:

```
style={!id && {cursor: "normal"} || null}
```

Example:

```js
const Foo = props => <div style={!props.id && {color: "green"} || null}>Testing</div>;

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Foo id="a" />
    <Foo />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
```

Comment: *(Sorry, I was defining the style if `id` **was** defined. I've fixed it now, hit refresh.)*